# Select string in HTML tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have  a script like :

```
    var h = document.getElementById('price');
    var pric= node.h;
    var total=parseInt(pric);

    var tot = 0;
    tot = total*2;
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML=tot;
```

this html code

```
<div id='price'>4000</div>
<div id='p'></div>
```

is there any wrong with the script? because i have error from js hint :

Missing radix parameter

Comment: where have you defined `node` ? you must get exception on this line `var pric= node.h;`

Answer (score 1):

since you tagged in jQuery, try this:

```
var total = $("#price").html() // get the html
total = total * 2;             // process it
$("#p").html(total)            // put it back
```

The implementation is more semantic and a little easier to understand.

Demo in a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ny9uW/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with parseInt.

parseInt(string, radix);

`var total = parseInt(pric, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

Problems

1. Remove `node.h`
2. Use [parseInt(string, radix)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), to convert text to integer
3. Use `innerHTML` property

Use

```
var price = document.getElementById('price');
var total=parseInt(price.innerHTML, 10);
var tot = 0;
tot = total*2;
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML=tot;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g5jqf/)